# How to make a confusion matrix with a keras model and TFrecords data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfrecord

I have trained a keras model which uses TFrecords because the training data and also validation data does not fit into memory. Now I would like to do a confusion matrix but the classic method which uses numpy arrays or "in-memory" tensors will not work. (with tf.math.confusion_matrix for example)

Is there any way I can do confusion matrix which from TFrecords simply? Even if the amount data is huge, making a confusion matrix should not eat too much memory. (Answers saying "No because..." will also be very helpful to me.)

Or I will just have to work with a smaller validation data?

Comment: You can find the details about all the matrix including confusion matrix with different types of data supported in this official documentation from Tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/metrics